# How to list directory contents of an FTP connection

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I can't find a tutorial on this. In VB.NET I want to do a command such as:

```
Dim array1() as string = ListFilesInFolder("www.example.com/images")
```

I know this is probably not going to be that simple, but can anyone point me to a tutorial or anything?

Comment: GoogleFu: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229716.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use this free library http://netftp.codeplex.com/

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.FtpClient

Sub Main
    using ftp = new FtpClient()

        ftp.Host = "www.example.com"
        ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("yourFTPUser", "yourFTPPassword")
        ftp.SetWorkingDirectory("/images")
        for each item in ftp.GetListing(ftp.GetWorkingDirectory())

            select case item.Type
                case FtpFileSystemObjectType.Directory:
                    Console.WriteLine("Folder:" + item.FullName)
                case FtpFileSystemObjectType.File:
                    Console.WriteLine("File:" + item.FullName)
            End Select
        Next
    End Using    
End Sub
```

of course I'm assuming that www.example.com is a FTP server.

**AN IMPORTANT NOTE:** The library requires the complete `Framework 4.0`. You should go to the Build Page of your `Project Properties`, click on the `Advanced Options` and select `Framework 4.0` instead of `Framework 4.0 Client Profile`

Comment: `Imports System.Net` needed

Comment: Steve, adding that made the errors go away, but when I click run in vb.net, it throws errors such as 

"Error 4 'FtpFileSystemObjectType' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

Yes, I have added a reference in the project and imports on the DLL and the system.net

Comment: Do you have also the `Imports System.Net.FtpClient` ? Missing this seems to be the only reason for your error. I have tried my example above and works without problems

Comment: That's the weird thing. I have that too! Hmmmm!

Comment: another weird thing, on "Imports System.Net.FtpClient" it underlines it in green and on one of my code lines error thrown as FtpClient not defined.

Comment: Got it. You are using the Framework Client Profile. The library requires the Full Framework. You should go to the Build Page of Project Properties, select the Advanced Options and select Full Framework instead of Framework Client Profile

Comment: gah! another error! "Could not find schema information for the attribute 'sku'." 

there are 3 of these same type of errors. this is after i set it to the full framework.

Comment: got it working!!! by the way, make sure your ftp credentials log you into the correct folder. otherwise when you do the 'ftp.SetWorkingDirectory("/images")' line of code, you will get an invalid directory error.

Answer (score 2):

The following method will work for `framework 3.5` and higher, I know this question is 3 years old but I ran into a situation where I need to list FTP directories in a `framework 3.5` project So I wrote following code by referring [*How to: List Directory Contents with FTP*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229716(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
Imports System.Net

Dim Dirlist As New List(Of String) 'I prefer List() instead of an array
Dim request As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.example.com/images"), FtpWebRequest)

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("USER_NAME", "PASSWORD")

Dim response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
Dim responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream

    Using reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)
          Do While reader.Peek <> -1
             Dirlist.Add(reader.ReadLine)
          Loop
    End Using
response.Close()
```

Comment: Also `Imports System.IO` for this answer

Comment: And `Imports System.Collections.Generic` for `List (Of String)` too