# Download all files and sub-directories from FTP folder in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, ftp

I searched all over the internet about my question but I found answer for C# only, but none for VB.NET.

I want to download all the files and sub-directories of a directory on my FTP server.

I am currently doing it by downloading a ZIP file from my FTP server and extracting it but this is not a good method.

Thanks!

Comment: See [How to list directory contents of an FTP connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14076973/1115360).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Download all files and subdirectories through FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038676/c-sharp-download-all-files-and-subdirectories-through-ftp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I KNOW YOU MIGHT BE LAZY TO READ ALL THAT, BUT THIS IS THE ANSWER!!! THE CODE IS AT THE END :D***

Hello,

It is very simple to do using the WinSCP library which is available for C# and VB.NET - here is the full answer:

Firsly, install the WinSCP library to your project, see here: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#downloading_and_installing_the_assembly

Or if you are lazy to do it, then just download the library and add the DLL file as a reference in your project.

And now let's download the whole directory including its files and its sub-directories to the local storage.

You have 2 options:

- [Session.GetFiles](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles) to download even if the files & directories are already downloaded.
- [Session.SynchronizeDirectories](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_synchronizedirectories) to download the files & directories if they does not exists, and also will download the the modified files which already exists. (BEST and better than the first option).

I used the second option of course because it is the best one ever. However, if you want to use the Session.GetFiles method... you can see the VB.NET example here: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles#vbnet

And here is how I used the second option: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_modified_files

As you can see, everything is explained great!

> Basically use `synchronize local` instead of `get` and `synchronize remote`
>   instead of `put`.
>
> With WinSCP .NET assembly that means, use
>   Session.SynchronizeDirectories, with argument mode set to
>   SynchronizationMode.Remote or SynchronizationMode.Local instead of
>   Session.GetFiles or Session.PutFiles respectively.

And as I wanted to download the files from the FTP Server to my local PC, then here is what I used (SynchronizeDirectories):

1. So yes! Of course `Imports WinSCP` first :-)
2. Use this code, because the code on https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_synchronizedirectories#vbnet is for SFTP (port 22) and not FTP (port 21) ... and also it uses `SynchronizeMode.Remote` which uploads from your PC to the FTP server , so in the code below I replaced `.Remote` with `.Local`

   ```
   Public Shared Function Main() As Integer

       Try 
           ' Setup session options
           Dim sessionOptions As New SessionOptions
           With sessionOptions
               .Protocol = Protocol.Ftp
               .HostName = "example.com"
               .UserName = "user"
               .Password = "mypassword"
           End With

           Using session As New Session
               ' Will continuously report progress of synchronization
               AddHandler session.FileTransferred, AddressOf FileTransferred

               ' Connect
               session.Open(sessionOptions)

               ' Synchronize files
               Dim synchronizationResult As SynchronizationResult
               synchronizationResult = _
                   session.SynchronizeDirectories( _
                       SynchronizationMode.Local, "d:\www", "/home/martin/public_html", False)

               ' Throw on any error
               synchronizationResult.Check()
           End Using

           Return 0
       Catch e As Exception
           Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e)
           Return 1
       End Try

   End Function

   Private Shared Sub FileTransferred(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TransferEventArgs)

       If e.Error Is Nothing Then
           'Console.WriteLine("Upload of {0} succeeded", e.FileName)
       Else
           'Console.WriteLine("Upload of {0} failed: {1}", e.FileName, e.Error)
       End If

       If e.Chmod IsNot Nothing Then
           If e.Chmod.Error Is Nothing Then
               'Console.WriteLine("Permisions of {0} set to {1}", e.Chmod.FileName, e.Chmod.FilePermissions)
           Else
               'Console.WriteLine("Setting permissions of {0} failed: {1}", e.Chmod.FileName, e.Chmod.Error)
           End If
       Else
           'Console.WriteLine("Permissions of {0} kept with their defaults", e.Destination)
       End If

       If e.Touch IsNot Nothing Then
           If e.Touch.Error Is Nothing Then
               'Console.WriteLine("Timestamp of {0} set to {1}", e.Touch.FileName, e.Touch.LastWriteTime)
           Else
               'Console.WriteLine("Setting timestamp of {0} failed: {1}", e.Touch.FileName, e.Touch.Error)
           End If
       Else
           ' This should never happen during "local to remote" synchronization
           'Console.WriteLine("Timestamp of {0} kept with its default (current time)", e.Destination)
       End If

   End Sub
   ```

Don't forget to replace the credentials and the paths..

One more thing? Good luck on your project! :-)

Answer (score 1):

*Translating my answer to [C# Download all files and subdirectories through FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37038676/850848) to VB.NET:*

The `FtpWebRequest` does not have any explicit support for recursive file operations (including downloads). You have to implement the recursion yourself:

- List the remote directory
- Iterate the entries, downloading files and recursing into subdirectories (listing them again, etc.)

Tricky part is to identify files from subdirectories. There's no way to do that in a portable way with the `FtpWebRequest`. The `FtpWebRequest` unfortunately does not support the `MLSD` command, which is the only portable way to retrieve directory listing with file attributes in FTP protocol. See also [Checking if object on FTP server is file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36895021/850848).

Your options are:

- Do an operation on a file name that is certain to fail for file and succeeds for directories (or vice versa). I.e. you can try to download the "name". If that succeeds, it's a file, if that fails, it's a directory.
- You may be lucky and in your specific case, you can tell a file from a directory by a file name (i.e. all your files have an extension, while subdirectories do not)
- You use a long directory listing (`LIST` command = `ListDirectoryDetails` method) and try to parse a server-specific listing. Many FTP servers use *nix-style listing, where you identify a directory by the `d` at the very beginning of the entry. But many servers use a different format. The following example uses this approach (assuming the *nix format)

```
Sub DownloadFtpDirectory(
        url As String, credentials As NetworkCredential, localPath As String)
    Dim listRequest As FtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
    listRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails
    listRequest.Credentials = credentials

    Dim lines As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

    Using listResponse As FtpWebResponse = listRequest.GetResponse(),
          listStream As Stream = listResponse.GetResponseStream(),
          listReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(listStream)
        While Not listReader.EndOfStream
            lines.Add(listReader.ReadLine())
        End While
    End Using

    For Each line As String In lines
        Dim tokens As String() =
            line.Split(New Char() {" "}, 9, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        Dim name As String = tokens(8)
        Dim permissions As String = tokens(0)

        Dim localFilePath As String = Path.Combine(localPath, name)
        Dim fileUrl As String = url + name

        If permissions(0) = "d" Then
            If Not Directory.Exists(localFilePath) Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(localFilePath)
            End If
            DownloadFtpDirectory(fileUrl + "/", credentials, localFilePath)
        Else
            Dim downloadRequest As FtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(fileUrl)
            downloadRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
            downloadRequest.Credentials = credentials

            Using downloadResponse As FtpWebResponse = downloadRequest.GetResponse(),
                  sourceStream As Stream = downloadResponse.GetResponseStream(),
                  targetStream As Stream = File.Create(localFilePath)
                Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(10240 - 1) {}
                Dim read As Integer
                Do
                    read = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                    If read > 0 Then
                        targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, read)
                    End If
                Loop While read > 0
            End Using
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Use the function like:

```
Dim credentials As NetworkCredential = New NetworkCredential("user", "mypassword")
Dim url As String = "ftp://ftp.example.com/directory/to/download/"
DownloadFtpDirectory(url, credentials, "C:\target\directory")
```

---

If you want to avoid troubles with parsing the server-specific directory listing formats, use a 3rd party library that supports the `MLSD` command and/or parsing various `LIST` listing formats; and recursive downloads.

For example with [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) you can download whole directory with a single call to the [`Session.GetFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles):

```
' Setup session options
Dim SessionOptions As SessionOptions = New SessionOptions
With SessionOptions
    .Protocol = Protocol.Ftp
    .HostName = "ftp.example.com"
    .UserName = "user"
    .Password = "mypassword"
End With

Using session As Session = New Session()
    ' Connect
    session.Open(SessionOptions)

    ' Download files
    session.GetFiles("/directory/to/download/*", "C:\target\directory\*").Check()
End Using
```

Internally, WinSCP uses the `MLSD` command, if supported by the server. If not, it uses the `LIST` command and supports dozens of different listing formats.

The [`Session.GetFiles` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles) is recursive by default.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: This return 550 File Unavailable :(

Comment: What are you referring to by *"this"*?

Comment: There are two completely different solutions in my answer. Which one are you referring to?